# orientDB multiple connection from same pool one with transaction and without

Tags: transactions, orientdb

I am planning on a design where I will acquire two connections from the same pool(plocal). start a transaction on just one connection and not on the other. I would like to use both these database connections in the same procedure and use the non transaction connection to do schema calls and the transaction connection to make record level calls that support transaction. will this approach work?

Answer (score 1):

As regards the scheme of operations, as suggested by the [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Schema.html), "Changes to the scheme are not transactional. You must execute These commands outside of a transaction." While for the records management is best managed as transitional (especially for update). It usually depends on what context you are talking.

Comment: That part is clear. ie "changes to schema cannot be part of a transaction". The question is, can we use two connections from the same pool (plocal). one for the schema changes (so 'no' begin() will be called on this connection). and another connection for record updates ( begin() will be called on this connection). can both these operations be used in the same method call using both these connections? I am trying to intermingle schema changes with record changes in one call and I want the record changes to be part of a transaction while the schema changes need not be.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have researched the Graph database API seems to handle this case automatically by using the executeOutsideTx methods internally for changes that involves the schema.